# Can you compute $\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx$ more precisely than $1.20206$ and do a comparision with $\zeta(3)$?

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, logarithms, improper-integrals, online-resources

I know from **Wolfram Alpha** that $$\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx=1.20206$$ and in the other hand, too from this online tool that
$$\int\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx=\mathrm{Li}_3(x)-\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\log(x)+constant.$$

> **Question.** I would like made a comparision, and need obtain $$\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx,$$
>   more precisely than $1.20206$. I believe that could be $\zeta(3)$, but now I don't sure, and I don't know if holding this claim could be deduce easily.
>
> Can you compute $\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx$ more precisely than $1.20206$ to discard that this value is $\zeta(3)$, Apéry constant, or claim that the equality $$\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx=\zeta(3)$$ holds and is known/easily deduced (perhaps from some of its known formulas involving integrals)?

This definite integral was computed as a summand, when I made some changes of variable in Beuker's integral (see [1]), and now i don't know if too I could be wrong in my computations.

I've searched in this site about this integral $\int\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}dx$, and in Wikipedia about a possible identity between $\zeta(3)$ and particular values of logarithmic integrals $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ and $\mathrm{Li}_3(x)$.

**References:**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant

Comment: My changes from Beukers integral (see Refereces) to obtain the integral as a summand (there were two summands) were first $x=e^{z/y}$, second $u=z/y$  and finally $v=e^u$. I hope that it has sense, and there are no mistakes. Too I am assuming that this way is know. Very thanks much all users.

Comment: Did you try expanding $\ln(1-x)$?

Comment: Taylor series ... expand $\ln(1-x)$ in terms of powers of $x$.

Comment: Seems like taylor series then by parts is the best way forward here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {z^k \over k^s} = z + {z^2 \over 2^s} + {z^3 \over 3^s} + \cdots \,.$$

Therefore, since $\log(1)=0$, we have:

$$\operatorname{Li}_3(1) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over k^3} = \zeta(3)$$

$$\operatorname{Li}_3(1)-\log(1)\operatorname{Li}_2(1) = \zeta(3)$$

It remains to show that $$\lim_{x\to0} \operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\log(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=0$$

Note that if $z<1$,

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {z^k \over k^2} = z + {z^2 \over 2^2} + {z^3 \over 3^2} + \cdots \\< z + {z \over 2^2} + {z \over 2^2}+ {z \over 4^2} + {z \over 4^2} + {z \over 4^2} + {z \over 4^2} + {z \over 8^2}+\cdots \leq z\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over 2^k} = 2z$$

Since $\log(z)<z$, for $z>1$, we also have $\log(z^2)<2z$ thus $\log(x)<2\sqrt{x}$. Thus $\log(\frac1x)>-2\sqrt{x}$, thus $\log(u)>-2\sqrt{\frac1u}$, thus  $0>\log(u)\operatorname{Li}_2(u)>-2\sqrt{u}$.

We may use the Squeeze Theorem to finish the result.

Comment: Then I understand is a bad question, since is easy to compute the limit (I will try it) too I will  try don't make more bad questions. Very thanks much @wythagoras. Now I don't know how comute the limit, but I will try it.

Comment: Very thanks for details @wythagoras

Answer (score 12):

There is a variety of possibilities *how* to show that this integral indeed equals $\zeta(3)$, i.e. Apéry's Constant. I would like to show some of them

**I: Taylor Series Expansion of $\log(1-x)$**

As it was first suggested within the comments (and done by FDP) we may expand the $\log(1-x)$ term as Taylor Series. Specifically, by using the MacLaurin Series of the aforementioned logarithm we obtain

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)}x\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}x\left[-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\int_0^1x^{n-1}\log(x)\mathrm dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left[-\frac1{n^2}\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\\
&=\zeta(3)
\end{align*}

This might be the most straightforward approach possible.

**II: Integration By Parts**

Choosing $u=\log(1-x)$ and $\mathrm dv=\frac{\log(x)}x$ we can apply Integration By Parts which gives

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)}x&=\underbrace{\left[\log(1-x)\frac{\log^2(x)}2\right]_0^1}_{\to0}+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(x)}{1-x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\log^2(x)\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^n\log^2(x)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac2{(n+1)^3}\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\\
&=\zeta(3)
\end{align*}

Again, we utilized a series expansion, this time the one of the geometric series.

**III: Integral Representation of the Zeta Function**

To use the [Integral Representation of the Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Mellin-type_integrals) here we need to reshape the integral a little bit. Starting with substitution $\log(x)\mapsto -x$ followed by Integration By Parts again we find

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)}x\mathrm dx&=-\int_\infty^0(-x)\log(1-e^{-x})\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_0^\infty x\log(1-e^{-x})\mathrm dx\\
&=\underbrace{\left[\frac{x^2}2\log(1-e^{-x})\right]_0^\infty}_{\to0}+\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1-e^{-x}}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac1{\Gamma(3)}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{3-1}}{e^x-1}\mathrm dx\\
&=\zeta(3)
\end{align*}

Overall this is more or less the same as the second approach, but I wanted to bring the integral representation into play. While this approach seems to omit the usage of a series representation we need it actually in order to prove the here used representation for the Zeta Function.

**IV: The Trilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_3(1)$**

Similiar to the second approach we may chose Integration By Parts as suitable technique but instead we will apply it with $u=\log(x)$ and $\mathrm dv=\frac{\log(1-x)}x$ to get

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)}x\mathrm dx&=\underbrace{\left[\log(x)(-\operatorname{Li}_2(x))\right]_0^1}_{\to0}+\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}x\mathrm dx\\
&=[\operatorname{Li}_3(x)]_0^1\\
&=\zeta(3)
\end{align*}

A quick look at the series representation of the Trilogarithm verifies the last line.

Comment: Hey, that's nicely done, but you took them all .

Comment: @Zacky Thank you! I'm sorry, but I couldn't resist `^^`

Answer (score 8):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln x}{x} dx\\
&=-\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}\right)\ln x\,dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln x\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\\
&=\zeta(3)
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

You can add this "weird" answer to the excellent
[$\texttt{@mrtaurho}$ long list](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3203757/85343):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x} =
\left.{\partial^{2} \over \partial\mu\,\partial\nu}\int_{0}^{1}
{\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{\mu} - 1}x^{\nu} \over x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{{\large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\large\,\,\nu\ =\ 0^{+}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\partial^{2} \over \partial\mu\,\partial\nu}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1}\,\dd x}
_{{\large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\large\,\,\nu\ =\ 0^{+}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\partial^{2} \over \partial\mu\,\partial\nu}\bracks{%
{\Gamma\pars{\nu}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{\nu + \mu + 1}} - {1 \over \nu}}
_{{\large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\large\,\,\nu\ =\ 0^{+}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\partial^{2} \over \partial\mu\,\partial\nu}\braces{{1 \over \nu}\bracks{%
{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{\nu + \mu + 1}} - 1}}
_{{\large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\large\,\,\nu\ =\ 0^{+}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\braces{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}
\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{\nu + \mu + 1}}}
_{{\large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\large\,\,\nu\ =\ 0^{+}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\braces{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}
\bracks{-\,{\gamma + \Psi\pars{\nu + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}} }}_{\ \nu\ =\ 0^{+}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\Psi\,''\pars{1} = \bbx{\zeta\pars{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

An informal argument:  $$\log (1-x) = - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}, \quad |x| < 1.$$  Then $$\frac{\log x \log(1-x)}{x} = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k \log x}{k+1},$$ and integrating term by term gives $$\int_{x=0}^1 x^k \log x \, dx = \left[ \frac{x^{k+1} \log x}{k+1} \right]_{x=0}^1 - \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x^k}{k+1} \, dx = - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}.$$  Therefore, $$\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{\log x \log(1-x)}{x} \, dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3} = \zeta(3).$$

Comment: Very thanks much @heropup

Comment: May I ask what is so *informal* about this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = e^{-y}$, we have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log x\log(1-x)}{x} dx
= \int_0^1 \frac{(-\log x)}{x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} dx
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 (-\log x) x^{n-1} dx\\
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty y e^{-ny} dy
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}
= \zeta(3)
$$
Please note that we can switch the order of summation and integration because all the individual terms are non-negative.

Comment: Very thanks much @achillehui incredible. I take notes from your solution.

Comment: @achillehui Are you exploiting Fubini-Tonelli with the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ and Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ to justify interchanging the series and integration?

Comment: @Dr.MV the last phrase "because all the individual terms are non-negative" is essentially Tonelli theorem.

Comment: @achillehui Yes, I know.  So, you are exploiting it then?

Answer (score 1):

The Beta function and Feynman's trick are another way to go:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx =\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b}\,dx\,\right|_{\alpha,\beta=0^+}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ I = \left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}\,\right|_{\alpha,\beta=0^+}\tag{2} $$
and by exploiting $\Gamma'(z) = \Gamma(z)\cdot\psi(z)$ we get:
$$ I = -\frac{1}{2}\psi''(2)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}=\color{red}{\zeta(3)}\tag{3} $$
as wanted.

Comment: I try understand your contribution too, now I am saturated. My changes to obtain the integral as a summand (there were two summands) were first $x=e^{z/y}$, second $u=z/y$  and finally $v=e^u$. I hope that it has sense. Very thanks much @JackD'Aurizio.

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\zeta(3)= \mathrm{Li}_3(1)=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{Li}_2(x)}xdx
=\int_0^1\left(- \int_0^x\frac{\ln (1-t)}tdt \right)d(\ln x)
= \int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{x}dx
$$